# How to install Swift 4 on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: software-installation, 17.10

According to [Swift's official website](https://swift.org/download/#Linux) it's supported platforms are:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Ubuntu 16.04
- Ubuntu 16.10

Is there any way to install it on a machine running Ubuntu 17.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a *prebuilt package* is not available for the Swift language and libraries, an option is to *build from source*. This is currently the case for Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10.

The Swift GitHub repository provides [steps to build Swift from source code](https://github.com/apple/swift#building-swift26).  The high-level build automation script `build-script` uses [CMake](https://cmake.org/) and [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) build tools.

The basic steps can be summarized as `apt-get` install prerequisites, download the Swift source and then run `build-script`.

```sh
## 1. Install prerequisites
sudo apt-get install git cmake ninja-build clang python uuid-dev libicu-dev icu-devtools libbsd-dev libedit-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev swig libpython-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config libblocksruntime-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev autoconf libtool systemtap-sdt-dev tzdata

## 2. Download source
mkdir swift-source
cd swift-source
# if using ssh…
git clone git@github.com:apple/swift.git
./swift/utils/update-checkout --clone-with-ssh
# alternately, if using http…
git clone https://github.com/apple/swift.git
./swift/utils/update-checkout --clone

## 3. Build source
cd swift
utils/build-script --release-debuginfo
```

URLs are provided to [contribute back](https://swift.org/contributing/) and [report bugs](https://bugs.swift.org/).

Use the search term "`17.10`" in the [Swift bug reporter](https://bugs.swift.org) to find information on issues (both resolved and unresolved) that others have already looked at for a source-base installation of Swift on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Nice and clean! :)

Answer (score 3):

On 17.10 this worked for me:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
umake swift
```

### Update

This also works on ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Some adjustment needed to the code above

Change:

```
git clone git@github.com:apple/swift.git
```

to

```
git clone https://github.com/apple/swift.git
```

or you will get an error - unless you are using ssh, in which case some other commands are missing.

Full Edit below:

```
# 1. Install prerequisites
sudo apt-get install git cmake ninja-build clang python uuid-dev libicu-dev icu-devtools libbsd-dev libedit-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev swig libpython-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config libblocksruntime-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev autoconf libtool systemtap-sdt-dev tzdata

# 2. Download source
mkdir swift-source
cd swift-source
git clone https://github.com/apple/swift.git
./swift/utils/update-checkout --clone


# 3. Build source
cd swift
utils/build-script --release-debuginfo
```